# remove the header and footer from the src in iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I am having simple issue regarding the iframe, I want to strip the header and footer from the source in the iframe, I tried clipping and pointing to the content but it is not working you have any thoughts?

My code is :

```
<div style="height:1500px;">
  <iframe src="url/#content" name="iframe_all" scrolling="no"
               frameborder="0" height="100%" width="100%" ></iframe>
</div>
```

where #content is the content in the source. It works fine one the first page of source but when the user clicks on the second page of the source in iframe again the header appears.

Comment: You have to listen to `load` event of an iframe and then remove the header and footer.

Comment: could you please explain you answer .sorry,i am new to this @sunpietro

Comment: Is the page(s) in the iframe loaded from the same domain as your page that contains the iframe?

Comment: yes they are from same domain

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access the content of the iframe with javascript:

```
var frame = document.querySelector("iframe");
header = frame.contentDocument.querySelector("header");
header.remove();
footer = frame.contentDocument.querySelector("footer");
footer.remove();
```

Or adapt the selectors for the elements you need.

Comment: It will only work if the page in the iframe is loaded from the same domain as the parent page (something tells me that's not the case because if it was, OP would likely have control of the iframe pages and could just edit them properly). You would also need to listen for load events in the iframe from location changes. I suggest you add a note about this in your answer.

Comment: @vyshnavi said it is from the same domain, so this should work good.

Comment: i have to give the id of the iframe in that script ? how to use that script ?

Answer (score 1):

I have the simple issue and I tried this code...

```html
<iframe width="100%" height="100%" src="url/#content_id" frameborder="0" scrolling="no">
</iframe>
```

Comment: Although this code may help to solve the problem, it doesn't explain _why_ and/or _how_ it answers the question. Providing this additional context  would significantly improve its long-term value. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, including what limitations and assumptions apply.